# np.where multiple return values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Using pandas and numpy I am trying to process a column in a dataframe, and want to create a new column with values relating to it. So if in column x the value 1 is present, in the new column it would be a, for value 2 it would be b etc

I can do this for single conditions, i.e

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col_1'] == 1, a, n/a)
```

And I can find example of multiple conditions i.e if x = 3 or x = 4 the value should a, but not to do something like if x = 3 the value should be a and if x = 4 the value be c.

I tried simply running two lines of code such as :

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col_1'] == 1, a, n/a)
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col_1'] == 2, b, n/a)
```

But obviously the second line overwrites. Am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 18):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[(df['col_1'] == 1, 'new_col')] = a
df.loc[(df['col_1'] == 2, 'new_col')] = b
```

Or:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col_1'] == 1, a, np.where(df['col_1'] == 2, b, np.nan))
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['new_col'] = np.select([df['col_1'] == 1, df['col_1'] == 2],[a, b], default=np.nan)
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), if no match get `NaN` by default:

```
d =  { 0 : 'a',  1 : 'b'}

df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think numpy `choose()` is the best option for you.

```
import numpy as np
choices = 'abcde'
N = 10
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(1, len(choices) + 1, size=N)
print(data)
print(np.choose(data - 1, choices))
```

Output:

```
[5 1 4 4 4 2 4 3 5 1]
['e' 'a' 'd' 'd' 'd' 'b' 'd' 'c' 'e' 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

you could define a dict with your desired transformations. 
Then loop through the a DataFrame column and fill it.

There may a more elegant ways, but this will work:

```
# create a dummy DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randint(2, size=(6,4)), columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'],  index=range(6)  )

# create a dict with your desired substitutions:
swap_dict = {  0 : 'a',
               1 : 'b',
             999 : 'zzz',  }

# introduce new column and fill with swapped information:
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i, 'new_col'] = swap_dict[  df.loc[i, 'col_1']  ]

print df
```

returns something like:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4 new_col
0      1      1      1      1       b
1      1      1      1      1       b
2      0      1      1      0       a
3      0      1      0      0       a
4      0      0      1      1       a
5      0      0      1      0       a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the pandas [Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) instead of where.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1' : [1,2,4,2]})
print(df)

def ab_ify(v):
    if v == 1:
        return 'a'
    elif v == 2:
        return 'b'
    else:
        return None

df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].map(ab_ify)
print(df)

# output:
#
#    col_1
# 0      1
# 1      2
# 2      4
# 3      2
#    col_1 new_col
# 0      1       a
# 1      2       b
# 2      4    None
# 3      2       b
```